# .NET C# Web API INSERT

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, webapi

I am learning Visual Studio 2019 and I am trying to build a Web API using ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework).

I am using Postman to post the values to my SQL Server database.

In my ValuesController, under Post, I have the following:

```
public string Post([FromBody] string value)
{
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Employees (Id,FirstName,LastName,email,userlevel) 
    VALUES ('"+value+"', '"+value+"', '"+value+"', '"+value+"', '"+value+"')", con);
  con.Open();
  int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();
  if(i == 1)
  {
    return "Record inserted with the value as " + value;
  }
  else
  {
    return "Try again";
  }
}
```

I run the application and paste the URL into Postman with the following parameters:

```
{
"Id": 10,
"FirstName": "Michael",
"LastName": "Jordan",
"email": "mjordan@goat.com",
"userlevel": 9
}
```

I get the following output:

```
"Record inserted with the value as "
```

The record saved, but it was inserted with an Id of 0.  All of the other fields are blank.

I originally had the SqlCommand coded like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Employees (Id,FirstName,LastName,email,userlevel) 
  VALUES ('"+value+"')", con);
```

But I was receiving the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'There are more columns in the INSERT statement than 
values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of 
columns specified in the INSERT statement.'
```

How can I get the INSERT query to function properly so that it will insert all of the parameters?

Comment: **Please** [parameterize your queries](https://xkcd.com/327/)... do not concatenate them together with your raw values...

Comment: `VALUES ('"+value+"')"` what's this part of query ?

Comment: The model binder for [`[FromBody]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#frombody-attribute) works with complex types, like a class.  You should create a model for your POST body so it can properly be binded to, and then you can replace all of those `value` with the properties of the class.

Comment: @AFarmanbar - I'm not sure how to answer that question.  I do know that if I write the INSERT with just a single column and use a single value, the query runs and inserts the single value (I hope that makes sense).

Comment: `'"+value+"'` it's just a single string value because you encircle it by `'`

Comment: @AFarmanbar - Did I not write it correctly?

Comment: @JohnBeasley it seems no, as broots Waymb said, parameterize your query

Comment: @AFarmanbar - I am not sure how parameterize a query in .NET.  The link that broots provided does not indicate how to parameterize anything, unless I'm reading it wrong.

Comment: @JohnBeasley Do you want me to teach you some best practice in correct way?

Answer (score 1):

as you are sending an object, you should receive and object, not a string. you could declare something like this as the parameter type:

```
  public class UserDTO
  {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public string Email { get; set; }
     public int userlevel { get; set; }
  }
```

Also, remove the single quotes from the value, as it will  understand as you are trying to insert the string 'value'.
And better yet, what Broots said, parameterize  your queries (look at the cmd .Parameters collection)

You can place the class in a new file userDTO.cs
The implementation could be something like this:

```
  public string Post([FromBody] userDTO user)
  {
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Insert Into Employees (Id,FirstName,LastName,email,userlevel) 
   
       VALUES(@Id,@FirstName,@LastName,@Email,@userlevel)", con);


     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", user.Id));
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", user.FirstName));
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", user.LastName));
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Email", user.Email));
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userlevel", user.userlevel));
```

.......

Comment: I am not sure where to put this class.  My apologies, I'm still learning.